# ART and d3 barchart in react native

Tags: d3.js, charts, react-native

I'm trying to make a react native barchart to visualize waveform data from my Java component.

But i can't use d3.select as in this example because i use ART and not SVG:

http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/making-a-bar-chart

So i need to create the svg path for the barchart, but i can't get this to work using d3.shape.

ive tried using the d3.shape step but that doesn't give the desired result.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I'm not expert but I attended to this talk: https://speakerdeck.com/hswolff/react-native-and-d3js And it was exactly about this. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

Please do the following, before that install the following packages in your application

1. d3-scale
2. d3-shape
3. d3-format
4. d3-axis
5. d3-path
6. d3

create a file BarChart.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, ART, Dimensions, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';

const {
    Surface,
    Group,
    Rectangle,
    ClippingRectangle,
    LinearGradient,
    Shape,
    Text,
    Path,
    Transform
} = ART;

import {
    max,
    ticks
} from 'd3-array'

import * as scale from 'd3-scale';
import * as shape from 'd3-shape';
import * as format from 'd3-format';
import * as axis from 'd3-axis';
import * as path from 'd3-path';
import Colors from '../../color.js';
const d3 = {
    scale,
    shape,
    format,
    axis,
    path,
};

import {
    scaleLinear,
    scaleBand,
    scaleTime
}  from 'd3-scale';

const colours = {
    black: 'black',
    blue: 'steelblue',
    brown: 'brown'
}

const data = [
    {frequency: 5, letter: 'a'},
    {frequency: 6, letter: 'b'},
    {frequency: 4, letter: 'c'},
    {frequency: 1, letter: 'd'},
    {frequency: 2, letter: 'e'},
    {frequency: 3, letter: 'f'}
];

class Bar extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.createBarChart = this.createBarChart.bind(this);
        this.drawLine = this.drawLine.bind(this);            
        this.getRandomColor = this.getRandomColor.bind(this);
    };

    getRandomColor() {
        return '#' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(-6);
    }               

    drawLine(startPoint, endPoint) {
        var path = d3.path.path();
        path.lineTo(startPoint, endPoint);
        return path;
    }

    createBarChart(x, y, w, h) {
        var path = d3.path.path();
        path.rect(x, y, w, h);
        return path;
    }

    render() {
        const screen = Dimensions.get('window');
        const margin = {top: 50, right: 25, bottom: 200, left: 25}
        const width = screen.width - margin.left - margin.right
        const height = screen.height - margin.top - margin.bottom

        const x = d3.scale.scaleBand()
            .rangeRound([0, width])
            .padding(0.1)
            .domain(data.map(d => d.letter))

        const maxFrequency = max(data, d => d.frequency)

        const y = d3.scale.scaleLinear()
            .rangeRound([height, 0])
            .domain([0, maxFrequency])

        const firstLetterX = x(data[0].letter)
        const secondLetterX = x(data[1].letter)
        const lastLetterX = x(data[data.length - 1].letter)
        const labelDx = (secondLetterX - firstLetterX) / 2

        const bottomAxis = [firstLetterX - labelDx, lastLetterX + labelDx]

        const bottomAxisD = d3.shape.line()
                                .x(d => d + labelDx)
                                .y(() => 0)
                                (bottomAxis)

        const leftAxis = ticks(0, maxFrequency, 5)

        const leftAxisD = d3.shape.line()
                            .x(() => bottomAxis[0] + labelDx)
                            .y(d => y(d) - height)
                            (leftAxis)
        const notch = 5
        const labelDistance = 9
        const emptySpace = "";
        return(
            <View>
            <Surface width={screen.width} height={screen.height}>
                <Group x={margin.left} y={margin.top}>
                    <Group x={0} y={height}>
                        <Group key={-1}>
                            <Shape d={bottomAxisD} stroke={colours.black} key="-1"/>
                              {
                                data.map((d, i) =>(
                                    <Group
                                        x={x(d.letter) + labelDx}
                                        y={0}
                                        key={i + 1}
                                    >
                                        <Shape d={this.drawLine(0, notch)} y2={notch} stroke={colours.black}/>
                                        <Text
                                          y={labelDistance}
                                          fill={colours.black}
                                          font="18px helvetica"
                                        >
                                          {d.letter}
                                        </Text>
                                    </Group>
                                ))
                              }
                        </Group>
                        <Group key={-2} >
                            <Shape stroke={colours.black} d={leftAxisD} key="-1"/>
                            {
                                leftAxis.map((d, i) => (
                                    <Group x={0} y={y(d)-height} key={i + 1}>
                                        <Shape d={this.drawLine(notch, 0)} stroke={colours.black}/>
                                        <Text
                                            fill={colours.black}
                                            x={-15}
                                            y={-labelDistance}
                                            font="18px helvetica"
                                        >
                                            {d + emptySpace}
                                        </Text>
                                    </Group>
                                ))
                            }
                        </Group>
                        {
                            data.map((d, i) => (
                                <TouchableWithoutFeedback key={i} >
                                    <Shape
                                        d={this.createBarChart(x(d.letter), y(d.frequency) - height, x.bandwidth(), height - y(d.frequency))}
                                        fill={this.getRandomColor()}
                                        >
                                    </Shape>
                                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                            ))
                        }
                    </Group>
                </Group>
            </Surface>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = {
  container: {
    margin: 20,
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 15,
    marginTop: 5,
    fontWeight: 'normal',
  }
};


export default Bar;
```

Then in App.js File add the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native;
import './App.css';
import BarChart from './BarChart';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);       
    }

    render() {            
        return (
            <View>
                 <BarChart/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Thank you, hope this will help you.

Comment: Hey @Kalai, thanks for putting up this example. I have struggling for a while. I want to ask how would you add a line to the barchart, so you can have the bar showing 1 value and the line showing another?

Comment: Do you have any way to do same thing with using d3-axis?

Comment: d3-axis is not used... the sample is missleading. Sorry :(